# pyautogui - copying selected text

Tags: pyautogui

After manually selecting text in a browser window, I'd like to be able to use a hotkey to a .py file to copy the selected text to the Windows clipboard.

Have tried
`pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "c")`

and

```
pyautogui.keyDown('ctrl')
pyautogui.press('c')
pyautogui.keyUp('ctrl')
```

But neither works. From trying to troubleshoot this in a .ipynb (Jupyter notebook) file, it seems the issue is Window focus. If I do:

```
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "c")
```

And manually alt-tab from the code editor to the browser window with selected text, it works fine. Trying to automate the alt-tab doesn't seem to work b/c the alt-tab window stays on screen instead of briefly flashing the way it does when manually executed.

```
pyautogui.hotkey("alt", "tab") # alt-tab
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "c")    #copy
```

So how can I select text in a browser window and then run .py file via hotkey but have the Window focus switch back to browser window before `pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "c")` executes?

Comment: Is it mandatory to select the info manually? Like, after selecting is there something that stopping you from using "ctrl+c"?

Comment: @ShahriarRahmanZahin I'm running a script that uses the last item in clipboard. So my current workflow is select browser text manually, press CTRL+c to copy text into clipboard, then press hotkey that launches python script. I'm trying to incorporate the CTRL+C into the python script as that would eliminate that manual step. Speed is important in this use case; if it was not important, I would not bother.

Comment: so, only thing you need now is copying the selected data right after you run the py script?

Comment: @ShahriarRahmanZahin no, I wish to copy the selected data as the first step in my py script (the script manipulates this data).

Comment: ok ok, I meant like this is where the code is not working right? Let me check and find a way to copy paste :)